# main.dart error child: Column( in the default flutter app

Tags: flutter

I'm getting an error in the default start app for Flutter in the child: Column( line red underline on the (

I have tried uninstalling everything and reinstalling but still see the error

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please add error log and describe, your question little further. so that, we can help you better

Comment: please share your code, it seems like you are either forgetting a semi column or having an missing/extra parahthesis.

Answer (score 1):

I recently went through something like that. I was getting an error in default scaffold but was able to solve it with help of an expert.
I think you mistakenly modified the flutter source code.    Try the following steps to solve the problem:

Navigate to the flutters main directory, then run **`git status`**, if no error it  will display **no modification**,  else run the following code in flutter main directory(one after the other) :

- `git clean -xfd`
- `git stash save --keep-index`
- `git stash drop`
- `git pull`
- `flutter doctor`

> (Note: make sure you run from the main directory)